# Is there a word for "armed with nuclear weapon"

Tags: word-request

I was thinking that the adjective "nuclear" meant "armed with nuclear weapon", but while it's true, we can't distinguish it from "powered with nuclear fuel", which is what a nuclear submarine is, so is there an adjective specifically for this?

Let's take the following example to make the problem more apparent:

> The nuclear submarine was armed with nukes, so it was also a ___
>   submarine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Nuclear-armed" seems like the best fit for that sentence, since "nuclear" is often used to mean "uses nuclear technology" (eg. nuclear bomb, nuclear reactor, nuclear submarine). "Nuclear-armed" would be taken to mean "armed with a nuclear weapon" in this context rather than "armed with nuclear technology" or "powered with nuclear fuel".

Edit: One complication is the phrase "nuclear state" which is [sometimes used](https://www.scmp.com/week-asia/explained/article/2188958/explained-how-india-and-pakistan-became-nuclear-states) to mean "state armed with a nuclear weapon". However, nuclear-armed seems to be the more common adjective.